# Is it possible to build a Mac .framework in Qt using .pro file within Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, frameworks, qt-creator

Building a framework on Mac OSX is straightforward using XCode with its ready-made templates.
I'm wondering whether there's a simple way to do the same thing ie. define the output of a Qt Creator build to be a framework by using the .pro file.

At the moment, I'm stuck building my libraries, then manually constructing the directory structure for a framework with the libs, headers and ./Current and ./Version directories.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The functionality is offered by qmake. In your `.pro` file, you need:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += lib_bundle
```

This is documented here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-platform-notes.html#creating-frameworks

If you want the framework to be used for development, make sure the correct headers are copied to the bundle. `QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA` is used for this.

Comment: Thanks Nikos, I missed that in the doc - a google search often throws up tonnes of links to various versions, but that link is perfect.